# What is the resolution mechanism to localization resources in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: resource-files

How does SharePoint behave when it does not find resource file? (I'm interested specifically in SP2010 if the behavior was different across versions.)

I found errors in ULS log specifying it cannot load resource file for given feature. It is quite expected as the feature does not contain any resources, however on several places in the code there is used syntax for localized resource (e.g. `Direction="$Resources:Direction;"` attribute in List definition of schema.xml). These references to localized resource are clearly copy&paste mistakes. What is the exact behavior of SharePoint in such situations? Does it just write error in ULS log and uses empty string for the attribute value? I guess so as the application runs fine and no known issue arises expect the ULS entries. But surprisingly I haven't found any info on the behavior on the web..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When SharePoint is looking for a resource string in the resources directory under the 14 HIVE and does not find it, the reference to the resource will be displayed. For instance, if you use $Resources:MyResource,FeatureTitle; as the title property of a custom feature and that resource does not exist, SharePoint will display $Resources:MyResource,FeatureTitle; for the feature name in the UI.